# Where is audio SampleBuffer in OpenTok, TokBox ios SDK

Tags: ios, opentok, tokbox

I am using the OpenTok iOS sdk to stream from iphone to chrome. What I would like to do is record a high res version of the video while streaming.

Using a custom video capturer via the OTVideoCapture interface from [Example 2 Let's Build OTPublisher](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-ios-sdk-samples/), I can successfully record the video sample buffer to file. The problem is, I cannot find any reference to the audio data gathered from the microphone.

I assume its using a audioInput(AVCaptureDeviceInput), to an audioOutput(AVCaptureAudioDataOutput) via AVCaptureAudioDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate is used somewhere.

Does anyone know how to access it from the OpenTok iOS SDK?

Comment: why not just use the archiving API to record?

Comment: The reason we aren't using the archiving API is because we want the max resolution we can get. But we dont want to send that over the network, it would be too large to live stream. The goal is archive the low res stream, save a high res for later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection , fromConnection field will differentiate the audio and sound connection and provides the corresponding buffer.

To setup the audio input/output you can try in Let-Build-OTPublisher initCapture method

```
    //add audio input / outputs
AVCaptureDevice * audioDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];
_audioInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:audioDevice error:nil];
if([_captureSession canAddInput:_audioInput])
{
    NSLog(@"added audio device input");
    [_captureSession addInput:_audioInput];
}

_audioOutput = [[AVCaptureAudioDataOutput alloc] init];
if([_captureSession canAddOutput:_audioOutput])
{
    NSLog(@"audio output added");
    [_captureSession addOutput:_audioOutput];
}


[_audioOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:_capture_queue];
```

Comment: Nice. That is a lot simpler than I thought, I was trying to find where they add there own audio output and interrupt the delegate method. Thanks